# iPhone SDK bluetooth capabilities and their limitations

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, bluetooth

When I connect an iPhone to a mac computer, what are the limitations on what I can send over bluetooth?

My goal is to freely transmit data one-way from the iPhone to the OSX machine via the bluetooth. Is there a way to wrap your own communication class so that it sends any kind of data it wants? What are the limitations?

Can I send any data I please to the mac OS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using Bluetooth low energy ver 4.0 (CoreBluetooth Framework) ? Depending on your application it could be the best for you. Its supported on all latest iOS and Mac devices.

If you wan to use the Classic Bluetooth (Ver 3.0, 2.1 or 1.2)
Unfortunately currently is is not directly (easily) possible using Classic Bluetooth.
To do it ideally you would have needed the SPP profile (Serial Port Profile) but the iOS currently does not support SPP.
The iPhone can talk to the Mac (or any other device) using only the standard profiles it supports, and there is no direct access for your application to tap into standard profile data on the iOS device.